# How to display Week as number in AWS QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need to display Week as number in AWS QuickSight. There is no WEEK function under extract. truncDate has WK, but this function does not result as Week_number: truncDate('WK',{date}). Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help at all with more truncDate? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/truncDate-function.html

Comment: No, truncDate does not give a week number of the year. In java I use native query, which gives a week of the year: (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_created) as text) as month

Answer (score 4):

In the field wells click the dropdown for your date field, mouse over Format and select 'More formatting options'. On the left panel in the Custom dropdown type 'w'.

Answer (score 3):

Create a calculated field

```
dateDiff(truncDate('YYYY', mydate), mydate, 'WK')
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained before, you can do what you are looking for by going to the Field `Wells -> Datetime field (X or Y axis) -> Format -> More formatting Options -> Custom`.
You can use `W` or `w`, the first will give you the week number corresponding to the current week, while the latter may offset you by a week. For instance, using an aggregation by DAY, the date of `14-Jun-2021` gives me Week `25` when I use custom `w` and Week `24` when I choose `W`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want year and week combination then you can use customer format option and type 'Yw' (this will return 202121 - 2021 year and 21 week).